# Bad Request : Sending request to ASP.NET WebAPI from android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I have tried to look for the solution for this with no success so far,

I am trying to call my ASP.NET WEB API (localhost:port) from Xamarin.Android (MainActivity).

I checked the API properly in Postman and it works as shown in the following screenshot

[image: Postman screenshot]

My code in Xamarin MainActivity is the following

```
 try
            {
                using (var c = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();                                      

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://10.0.2.2:57348/api/remote"));

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Log.Info("myApp", "SUCCESS");                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.Info("myApp", "ERROR: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                    }

                }              


            }
            catch (Exception X)
            {
                Log.Info("myApp", X.Message);
                return X.Message;
            }
```

I believe that `10.0.2.2` is to connect to the `localhost` from emulator -

When I run the code I get the error status as `BadRequest`

I also tried something like the following

```
try 
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.0.2.2:57348/api/remote");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {        
            Log.Info("myApp", "Success");        
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception X)
    {
        Log.Info("myApp", X.Message);        
    }
```

I get `400 Bad Request`

400 Bad Request means I am doing something wrong as assuming that my code can connect to the API but the server is considering API Call as `invalid`?

Just in case if anyone wants to know the code in my API, its the following

```
public class remoteController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/remote
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

Anyone has any idea about this, I have been trying different things for hours with no luck.

Also just to add, I tried 'http://10.0.2.2:57348/api/remote' in my Android Emulator's Chrome and I still get `Bad Request` response as shown in the following screenshot

[image]

but trying the same on my machine (browser) or Postman works fine using `localhost`

[image]

Please help

**UPDATE:** 
Tried enabling External request on IIS Express  using this http://www.lakshmikanth.com/enable-external-request-on-iis-express/ 
No luck,

Comment: the bad request is saying invalid hostname, does the emulator or device have web connectivity?  Also double check the IP of the desktop being used.  I suspect you are using the IP that is assigned to your computer.

Comment: @mvermef yes, i have connectivity to the web - I also have Android Permissions set to access internet in Manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` - What IP should i be checking?

Comment: Ok verify `ip adress` of your desktop 10.0.2.2:port is not yours... since it never connects

Comment: Do you mean i should be using my computer's IP instead of 10.0.2.2? as my understanding was 10.0.2.2 gets mapped to localhost for the emulator?

Comment: what is desktop's ip address, since I assume that where you are programming, if its behind a firewall like your router with dhcp then its either 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x something

Comment: yes, its 192.168.1.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162566/discussion-between-mvermef-and-aliusman).

Comment: IIS binding issue since its related not allowing outside connections.

Comment: @mvermef yes I believe you are right, but I am using IIS Express - How can I allow outside connections in IIS Express - going to try this http://www.lakshmikanth.com/enable-external-request-on-iis-express/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is "bad" because the host header (in the request) is your 10.x.x.x. IP, and not localhost, which IIS Express won't accept.

We have an extension called "Conveyor", it's free and without configuration changes it opens up IIS Express to other machines on the network.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti#overview

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your response, and yes I tried that extension in visual studio but I was getting some error (I don't remember what it was) and there was some issues which made me uninstall the extension, I can't remember though. I think there is some issue with my approach, I know the IP 10.x.x.x won't be accepted as localhost but I also tried enabling external requests for IIS, didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because of cross origin error add this in startup.cs ( in configure method)

```
app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
```

Comment: He is using asp.net web api the problem is in the api that is not allowing cross origin request

Comment: CORS is OWIN in webapi don't think he has it installed. Again he is using `asp.net webapi` not `asp.net core`, huge difference, considering he is using ApiController, which is indeed old flavor of webapi

Comment: @mvermef trying your code gives me an error `cannot convert lambda expression to type 'CorsOptions'` ---- Although I tried the following and it didn't work either `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

Comment: @Aliusman not my code that is for `ASP.Net Core` which you are not using reference my first comment on your initial post ^^^